# React: update state with form data onChange using the spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update my state using the spread operator so I can pass form data in a http request, but it doesn't seem to be updating at all from what i can see in my console.logs.

I'm also getting the error 'TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance'. I need the data I pass in to be an object though.

```
import React from 'react'
import SuperAgent from 'superagent'
import { string } from 'prop-types'

class ContactForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      data: {}
    }
  }

  handleClick (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.submitForm()
  }

  onChange (e) {
    this.setState(...this.state.data, {[e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  submitForm () {
    const { data } = this.state
    SuperAgent
      .post('https://something.com')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .send({
        data: {
          'name': 'name',
          'formName': 'form',
          'emailName': 'email',
          data
        }})
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err || !res || !res.body) return console.log(err)
        window.location='/contact-form-successful.html'
      })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <section className='contact-form' id={this.props.id}>
          <form id='contact-form' method='post' action='#' onSubmit={this.handleClick}>
            <input
              name="username"
              type="text"
              value=''
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              name="email"
              type="email"
              value=''
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              name="birthdate"
              type="text"
              value=''
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <button>Send data!</button>
          </form>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default ContactForm

ContactForm.propTypes = {
  id: string
}

ContactForm.defaultProps = {
  id: 'contact-form'
}
```

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Your inputs aren't controlled. I updated my answer. Now should work!

Comment: thank you! that works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `setState` wrong

```
this.setState(...this.state.data, {[e.target.name]: e.target.value })
```

Should be

```
 const { target : { value, name } } = e
 this.setState(prevState => ({
     data: {
        ...prevState.data,
        [name]: value
     }
 }))
```

Also the input's `value` should reflect the `state` (controlled input)

```
<input
   name="username"
   type="text"
   value={this.state.username}
   onChange={this.onChange}
 />
```

Comment: Its rather one-way data binding, state's value gets reflected in respective `input`

Comment: Actually the correct term here is controlled. But you're right, isn't two way at all

Answer (score 1):

Your onChange method should rather do this :

```
 onChange (e) {
    this.setState(state => ({
        data: {
           ...state.data,
           [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }
    }))
  }
```

Comment: You were updating the whole state and not only the state.data property.

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax usage of spread operator would be like below:

```
  onChange (e) {
    this.setState({...this.state.data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
```

However, you dont need spread in using `setState` you only update what you need to.

Thus you would only set state like below:

```
  onChange (e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
```

If you want to rely on prior state value then you would have to use functional `setState`

```
  onChange (e) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }))
  }
```

Other than that you were also missing input's value to be retrieved from state of react component rather you were hardcoding it as `''` empty string thus value was never reflected in the input while your state kept getting updated with last key input.

```
        <input
          name="username"
          type="text"
          value={this.state.username}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <input
          name="email"
          type="email"
          value={this.state.email}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <input
          name="birthdate"
          type="text"
          value={this.state.birthdate}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
```

Comment: thanks, it won't let me type in the input boxees with these solutions?

Comment: You also have to set each input value to its respective state property

Comment: That was another problem along with first syntax issue, updated answer with correct input binding.